# Как динамически в add_rewrite_rule подставить слаг терма пользовательской таксономии

Tags: wordpress, регулярные-выражения, чпу

В файле functions.php есть функция taxonomy_rewrite_rule, которая перезаписывает URL. Каким образом можно подставить в регулярное выражение переменную, а именно слаг терма таксономии? Слаг таксономии в функции я достал с помощью соответствующих функций, но данная переменная почему-то пустая, хотя в других функциях в файле functions.php слаг таксономии данных способом достаётся.

```
function taxonomy_rewrite_rule() {

    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    $slug = $term->slug;

    add_rewrite_rule("^companies/" . $slug . "/([^/]+)/?$", 'index.php?companies=$matches[1]', 'top');  
}
add_action('init', 'taxonomy_rewrite_rule');
```

Comment: А что в переменной `$slug`? Нет ли там специальных символов? `preg_quote($slug)`?

Comment: В переменной $slug пусто, т.е. NULL, хотя там должен подхватиться слаг термина таксономии, например mashinostroenie. В других соседних функциях срабатывает, а в этой функции почему-то не хочет

Comment: Ага, тогда надо копать дальше. Кажется, дело не в регулярке.

Comment: Да, не в регулярке. Почему-то не срабатывает функция: $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); Хотя в других функция файла functions.php инфу о таксономии вытягивает

Comment: Основной запрос WP формируется позже события init, поэтому функции get_term_by и т.д. не возвращают ничего. Порядок загрузки описан, например, здесь: https://wpcafe.org/hacks/how-wordpress-works/

Comment: спс, теперь хоть знаю в чем причина и уже думаю дальше разберусь)

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, ответ, если решили проблему.